# Using Nokogiri and XPath to get nodes with multiple namespaced attributes

Tags: ruby, xml, xpath, nokogiri

From the following, I'd like to grab the text from the node containing the `xml:lang="en"` attribute.

```
<li><span class="literal"><span property="dbpedia-owl:abstract" xmlns:dbpedia-owl="http://dbpedia.org/ontology/" xml:lang="en">text</span></span></li>
```

Currently I'm using:

```
ns = {"xmlns" => "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"}
ns = {"xml" => "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"}`

array << doc.xpath("//span[@property='dbpedia-owl:abstract' and xmlns:dbpedia-owl='http://dbpedia.org/ontology/' and @xml:lang='en']").text`
```

I'm not sure if it's my XPath array or namespace declaration that is wrong, but either way I'm not doing something right.

Apologies if the question has been asked previously, but I couldn't find something combining namespaces and multiple attributes, so I might just be combining solutions that I found to those separate problems improperly. It might also be an issue with the `xmlsn:dbpedia-owl` value being a URL, but again, not sure.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not at my computer, so I can't test this, but I'd start with something like:

```
doc.at('span.literal').text
```

Namespaces are useful, but according to your sample you should be able to grab the text easily.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That works as well, though it grabs the first span.literal like my original script was doing, and I specifically need the English text. One example URL is http://dbpedia.org/page/Astro_Boy ; You can see in the source that the first span.literal is in Arabic (xml:lang="ar") which is what your suggestion / my original grabs.

Comment: And where in the question were those requirements listed? You said "I'd like to grab the text".